# how to transfer ether from one account to multiple account

Tags: remix

I have 3 account

1st account 1000 ether
2nd account 20 ether
3rd account 30 ether

now I want to transfer 100 ether from 1st account to both 2nd and 3rd account

Answer (score 3):

You are thinking on **batching** transactions.

If you worked with **bitcoin** before, this is quite straightforward as you can set N number of outputs to your transactions (therefore sending to multiple addresses).

On **Ethereum**, you need to have a **contract** in the middle to which you want to send 1 transaction with all the data you want to split inside and send separately to each address (through the contract).

A contract method might look like this :

```
function sendTo(address[] addrs, uint[] amounts) {
    for(uint i = 0; i < addrs.length; i++) {
        addrs[i].transfer(amounts[i]);
    }
}
```

Cheers