# Is there a protocol to transfer erc20 tokens to multiple addresses?

Tags: solidity, erc-20

I'm looking for something like described here:

[how to transfer ether from one account to multiple account](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/71261/how-to-transfer-ether-from-one-account-to-multiple-account)

I just thought it's such a common problem - isn't there an existing library (preferred) or  a trustworthy deployed project out there that does this?

Answer (score 1):

There is: [multisender.app](https://multisender.app/):

[image: Multisender Screenshot]

Source code: https://github.com/rstormsf/multisender

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that big, Security audited Projects Like uniswap would have something like this. The contract does not look Well maintained.